# Translating a excel formula to a sharepoint calculated column formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have two excel formulas that are driving me crazy trying to get them to work in SharePoint 2010.  Can anyone help with these?

FIRST:

```
=IF(AE206>=Q206,IF(AND(Q206>0,AE206>0,AG206>0),NETWORKDAYS(Q206,AE206,Holidays!$C$3:$C$17)-1,""),"")
```

At this point, I know `NEWORKDAYS` does not work, so I replaced it with `WEEKDAY`; I also know that `Holidays` does not work, so we completely decided not to include them

SECOND:

```
=IF(AI217<>"",AI217,IF(AH217<>"",AH217,IF(AG217<>"",AG217,AF217)))
```

I believe I need to use `ISBLANK` for this formula and not sure if <> works in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ISBLANK is what you can use, or NOT(ISBLANK(AI217)) if you do not want to rewrite your formula too much.

See https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List for the correct list of Functions & Syntax available in SharePoint; tested them on 2013, but I do not recall there where any changes to 2010.

You might be helped with the [CalcMaster BookMarklet](https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster) I put on GitHub.
It attaches itself to the textarea when editting a Calculated Column, giving you (error)feedback on every keypress. Saves a shitload (*are we allowed to curse on SO?*) of time when changing Formulas...